# Access response from spider in items pipeline in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have spider like

```
class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://example.com/url'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
```

And I have a pipeline class like this

```
class ProductsDataPipeline(object):
    """ Item pipeline for products data crawler """

    def process_item(self, item, spider):   
        return item
```

But I want get response argument of parse function in parse_item function without setting as an attribute to item object,Is it possible

Comment: I think what you need is a middleware, not a pipeline. A middleware can access requests and responses, read this: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not possible.

Responses are not forwarded to pipelines. You either have to store response in item or use some external storage to store response and fetch it in pipeline. Second option is much better, and avoids many problems that can result from storing response in item (e.g. memory problems). For example you save response to some form of storage in parse callback, save reference to this storage in item field, and fetch response from storage in pipeline.

But it really depends on what you are trying to do, response is available in [spider middleware process_spider_output](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_output) so perhaps you can use it instead of processing item in pipeline.

Comment: I just want save the response in a flat file is it good to do that directly from parse function of spider?

Comment: It depends. If you only need that for one spider its probably fine. If you need to do this for all spiders in project use middleware.